# Name worksheets based on cell value in another column

Tags: vba, excel

I am a bit new to VBA and here is my question

i have two cloumns in my sheet1

```
test        Name
1               A
2               B
```

Now i have code which runs and creates a new sheet for each value in cloumn "test".

For example,

when it runs the first time, 1 is fetched and my code runs and creates a new sheet and created sheet name is set as 1 (Based on value from fetched from test column). The second time, the process repeats with new sheet created and sheet name being 2

Now here is my qeustion.

**Is it possible for us to name the newly created sheets based on "Name" column rather than "test" column**

**I mean when 1 is fetched and new sheet is created, i want to name it as "A" rather than 1 and when the loop runs the second time, i want to name the new sheet created as "B" rather than 2**

Please help

Thanks

**UPDATE**

**Sample code**

```
    Dim ran As Range
    Dim cel As Object

    Set ran = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A100")

    For Each cel In ran

        If cel.value <> Empty Then

            ' this is mycode. am skipping it
            '<my code> ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            '    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= etc </mycode>

            ' once my code runs, a new sheet is created which as of now refrences
            ' to "test" column as said earlier. i want this to refer to "name"
            ' column when the loop runs so that the sheets are named based on
            ' "name" colum rather than "test"
            activesheet.name = cel

        Else
            Exit For

        End If
    Next cel
```

Comment: It certainly is possible. Where is your code?

Comment: If you don't want to show us the VBA code, then a quick hack would be to interchange the `test` and `Name` columns in your sheet. But be careful: 1) it might not work if the VBA detects the `test` by its header, and 2) it might breake some other VBA code/Excel formulas that relies on the fixed position of these columns.

Comment: @mehow : am afraid its not possible as it has confidential things. :( but my code inside the loop works fine. am able to do everything. i just dont know how to reference it to "Name" column rather than using test colum for naming the sheets

Comment: @Sriram You don't have to show us the whole code. Just the line that creates the worksheet. Feel free to obfuscate sheet names, columns numbers etc. but I think the Excel objects are not the intellectual property of your company. So, **that** you can show us. :-)

Comment: lol what can be confidential about VBA code that creates a new sheet and names it based on a value..??

Comment: @mehow : updated the sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the range of the cells that you use for naming; if the "Name" is on column adjacent to "test", then change:

```
activesheet.name = cel
```

to

```
activesheet.name = CStr(cel.Offset(0,1).Value)
```

and you should be fine.

Mind that you might have changed the `ran` to the range `"B2:B100"` but I'm not sure if you don't use the range `"A2:A100"` values in your code...

**Update**

If it were my code, I would also feel better to declare the right type for `cel`:

```
Dim cel  As Excel.Range
```

but this is not essential to your question.

Comment: Exactly what i was looing for. Thanks :)